# Redirect to controller action in IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

in my app during the first login I'm checking if the user already exists, and if he doesn't I want to redirect him to finish registration to Registration/Register action. I have the following code:

```
    public class OpenIdConnectOptionsPostConfigureOptions
        : IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public OpenIdConnectOptionsPostConfigureOptions(
            IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClientFactory));
        }

        public void PostConfigure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnTicketReceived = async ticketReceivedContext =>
                {
                    var userId = ticketReceivedContext.Principal.Claims
                        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

                    var apiClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("BasicAPIClient");

                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                        HttpMethod.Head,
                        $"/api/users/{userId}");
                    request.SetBearerToken(
                        ticketReceivedContext.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token"));

                    var response = await apiClient.SendAsync(
                        request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("UserStatus", "NewUser") };
                                                
                        ticketReceivedContext.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
                    }
                }
            };
        }        
    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to do it with redirect so as a workaround I'm adding a claim
`var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("UserStatus", "NewUser") };`
which I later check

```
[Authorize]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            if (User.HasClaim("UserStatus", "NewUser"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like below:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    ticketReceivedContext.Response.Redirect("XXX");
    ticketReceivedContext.HandleResponse();
}
```